# Relative paths to other sheets inside a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to put our food recipe collection into a Google Spreadsheet. On the first page we have an index of all the foods. Each recipe is located on a separate sheet.

We would like to be able to click on a food name on the index page and have the browser open up the recipe sheet of that food.

Is it possible to accomplish this in Google Spreadsheets without having to use complex absolute urls?

Answer (score 2):

Within the same document you do not need the complex absolute URL, just the 'gid' number is sufficient.

Go to a sheet you want to jump to from the first page, copy the last part of the URL, starting `#gid=` but include the following number or numbers. Go to your first sheet, select which cell to be the springboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and overwrite whatever is in Link by pasting the copy. Then Apply.