# Is there a URL anchor that opens to the rightmost sheet/tab within a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a Google Sheets link that ends in `/edit` or `/edit#gid=0`, it opens to the leftmost sheet.  I'm looking for the opposite.

I know how to link to a specific sheet (`/edit#gid=[ID number here]`), but in this case, new tabs are added to the right.  Is there some way to link to the rightmost sheet, whatever that may happen to be **at the time of clicking the link**, not at the time of linking?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't "anchors" for opening sheets based on their position, by the way,

- `/edit` opens the first sheet
- `/edit#gid=0`opens the default sheet, no matter of it's position

One workaround might be to use an on open trigger to activate the last sheet when the spreadsheet is opened but it only works for the spreadsheet owner and editors.

To learn about the basics of using Google Apps Script to automate Google Sheets and about triggers, please checkout the following official guides:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

This code use a simple `onOpen` trigger

```
function onOpen(e){
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  if(sheets.length > 1) sheets.slice(-1)[0].activate();
}
```

Related

- [Relative paths to other sheets inside a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46912/88163)
- [How can I create a URL for a specific cell in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79150/88163)